# Relay Compiler Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}"

Tags: graphql, relay

could not figure out why my query has syntax errors for hours.
I copy and paste the query to graphiql and it works fine. When I ran relay compiler against my js, it threw this error.
Does anyone have the same issue?

The weird thing is if I remove the "query HomeQuery", it gave different error to complain about operation name..

my code

```
import {graphql} from "react-relay";

const query = graphql`
    query HomeQuery {
        tasks {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

my package.json

```
...
    "relay": "relay-compiler --schema ../resources/schema.graphql --src ./pages/test"
...
```

I ran npm run-script relay

```
the log
 relay-compiler --schema ../resources/schema.graphql --src ./pages/test


Writing js
ERROR:
Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "}".
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! my-app2@0.1.0 relay: `relay-compiler --schema ../resources/schema.graphql --src ./pages/test`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app2@0.1.0 relay script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: 'great' DX ... error without pointing line? (will be fixed in v25 'production ready solution'?)  ... are you sure it's about this query?

Answer (score 0):

turnout it is just your schema cannot have empty

type Mutation {

}

after I revmoed the empty type Mutation, everything is working....